# Getting data from a Firebase - How to only get records with date in the future and sort the results chronologically

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code so far.. I'm a real beginner and I want to get all records that are in the future, then sort them chronologically.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service

  //var db = firebase.database();
  const preObject = document.getElementById('Agenda');
  const ulList = document.getElementById('AgendaList');

  // Create references

  const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('Event');

  // Synch object changes

  dbRefObject.on('child_added', snap => {

    var data = [];
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    var JSONValue = snap.val();
    li.innerHTML = '<h3>'+ JSONValue['Date'] + ' - ' + JSONValue['Time'] + '</h3><span class="status">'+JSONValue['Status']+'</span><p class="concert">'+ JSONValue['Concert'] + '</p><p class="artists">'+ JSONValue['Artists'] +'</p>';
    li.id = snap.key;
    ulList.appendChild(li);
```

Thanks for looking in to this...

Comment: Typically this would be something like `dbRefObject.orderByChild("Date").startAt("20191014")` (or whatever date format you use). If you can't get that to work, edit your question to include the updated code, **and** a sample of the JSON that you're trying to query (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Hello Frank, thanks for your feedback. I managed to make it work the way you described... only thing left is to format the date but I gues thats another thread to start. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Firebase returns the child nodes in the order of their keys.

If you want to order by the value of a specific child property, you can use a query. Typically this would be something like `dbRefObject.orderByChild("Date").startAt("20191014")` (or whatever date format you use).